# Server rendering with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

i'm developing a webapp in AngularJS (1.5) and Flask, and i'm self-taught.
My webapplication is not public, so any resource is reserved.

In the first version i manage rendering of the pages by AngularJS through ngRoute and resolve, but i've understood that is a mistake.
In the second version i'm changing the rendering of the page from Angular to Flask, but every time i've the same problem: Flask render a page, send it to Angular but Angular doesn't show it but instead it show the template in the routing. I've try many cases:

- render the login page with Angular and serve just a controller to call the server and load the server rendered page;
- render all with Flask and just a controller in Angular to manage the auth
- use the resolve instead a function in controller for manage the reserved page

For each case i've the same situation: server response with html rendered page, but it's not showed by Angular.

I've found some solutions about my problems: upgrade to Angular2.0 or implement Node.JS, or implement angular-server ... but i would like to avoid to add other components and understand what's wrong.

Part of the Angular routing code

```
var reserved = {
    name: "reserved",
    params: {aaa:true} }
var reservedContent = {
    name: "reserved.content",
    url: "/reserved",
    template: "<h1>Angular rendered</h1>" }
```

and in app.run

```
$transitions.onBefore({ to: 'reserved.*' }, function(t){
    var AuthService = t.injector().get('appAuth');
    var authorization = appAuth.authorization(t.to().url.substr(1), $rootScope.token);
    authorization.then(function()   {
        $rootScope.resource = t.to().url;
        pySrv.app($rootScope.resource)
        .then(function(data){
            console.log("The html server rendered page: " + data);
            console.log("The Angular template in state" + t.to().template);
            t.to().template = data;
            },
            function(data){
                console.log("Reject");  }   );
        },
        function(){
            $state.target("403");   }); });
```

I always see "Angular rendered" in the page.

Comment: Why is it a mistake to let angular do client side rendering?

Comment: Because when you load the home page, you can see the JavaScript code about the routing and make a survey of the webapp, even if you are a guest and don't logged in. The first version of my webapp works and is very fast, but it's wrong in the design.

Comment: Lots of ways to manage routing authorization in angular

Comment: I'm managing routing auth in Angular: actually i manage the authentication with Angular, jwt and Active Directory.
My only problem is show the server rendered page.

Comment: Then not clear what problem is

Comment: I've edit the post with part of the code. Thanks :-)

Comment: @charlietfl i've understood that there are some mistake about implementation and analisys on this project. I'm rebuilding from beginning. I'm back to developing but in these last years i've worked on networking, so i've restart to studying developing ;-) thank you so much